# How do we call this method?

Tags: soft-question, curves, plane-curves, parametrization

We want to study a parametric curve $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2, \ t\mapsto (x(t),y(t))$.

To proceed, we use the cartesian equation of a line $y=ax+b$ with $a\in \mathbb{R},b\in \mathbb{R}^{*}$ and determine the points of intersection with the parametric curve changing the value of $b$. Then it enables to have an idea of the drawing of the parametric curve.

Is this an established method of analyzing curves? If so, what is its name?

Comment: Are you referring to Frenet-Serre equations https://duckduckgo.com/?q=frenet+serret+formulas&t=h_&ia=web?

Comment: @gary The S-F equations are ${\bf T} ' = \kappa{\bf N}$ and ${\bf N} ' = - \kappa{\bf T}$. The OP's problem seems unrelated.

Comment: @FlybyNight: Yes, it was kind of a wild guess since I could not conceive of anything related.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve? You say that you "*want to study a parametric curve*", so I assume you already have a parametrisation. Are you trying to find a Cartesian equation?

Comment: @FlybyNight In fact, you have a cartesian equation of a line then you change the value of the real number $b$ (it's a sort of sweeping) and obtain a parametric curve.

Comment: Please could you give more details so that we can answer your question. I think I know the type of problem you mean, but there's no point guessing.

Comment: There is the dual algebraic curve and the convex conjugate, replacing a curve by the set of its tangent lines.

Comment: @FlybyNight it's a sweeping with a sort of hull...